# What is the cost per unit after exceeded the quota units in YouTube Data API v3

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using **YouTube Data API v3**. It gives 10000 free units per day. If exceeded the quota I want to know how much amount I needed to increase quota units.

Please any one say **what is the cost per unit** after exceeded the quota units limit in YouTube Data API v3.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any referenced way to pay for quota.

According to [YouTube Data API Overview](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota) about quota:

> Note: If you reach the quota limit, you can request additional quota by completing the [Quota extension request form](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form) for YouTube API Services.