# Consumption of queries via API Youtube v3

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I can't find any material that tells me what happens after consuming the 1,000,000 queries from the Youtube API.

I would like to know what happens when I consume the 1,000,000 queries available in the Youtube API v3?
What is the cost after that?

Comment: Duplicated with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68003000).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After that you get an exception that says you have reached your limit.

You will need to wait until the next day to make additional requests.

You can request a quota extension to increase the number of quota points you have.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Another question came to me and how do I increase this quota?

Comment: by filling out the [Quota extension form](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form)